# map() output adding a string to a string array Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, dictionary

using Python 3.6.1

```
time_vector = ['06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']

doublezeroes = "00"

time=map(str(time_vector), doublezeroes)

print(time)
```

I get map object at 0x7ff64a3580f0 with the <>

I need

`time = ['0600', '0700', '0800', '0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300', '0000', '0100', '0200', '0300', '0400', '0500', '0600']`

I am sure there might be an easier like append or insert just not sure how to get there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one which is almost same of your code with **lambda expression**`added:

```
time_vector = ['06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']

time=list(map(lambda k: k+'00', time_vector))

print(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably the following:

```
time = [v + doublezeroes for v in time_vector]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use map, simply append the string to the list:

```
In [1132]: new = [ s + '00' for s in time_vector]

In [1133]: new
Out[1133]: 
['0600',
 '0700',
 '0800',
 '0900',
 '1000',
 '1100',
 '1200',
 '1300',
 '1400',
 '1500',
 '1600',
 '1700',
 '1800',
 '1900',
 '2000',
 '2100',
 '2200',
 '2300',
 '0000',
 '0100',
 '0200',
 '0300',
 '0400',
 '0500',
 '0600']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function along with map to get output

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. This
>   function returns the sum of its two arguments: lambda a, b: a+b.
>   Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required.
>   They are syntactically restricted to a single expression.

```
time_vector = ['06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']

doublezeroes = "00"

timelist=list(map(lambda x:x+doublezeroes, time_vector))

print(timelist)
```

OUTPUT

```
['0600', '0700', '0800', '0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300', '0000', '0100', '0200', '0300', '0400', '0500', '0600']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.ljust`

**Ex:**

```
time_vector = ['06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']
doublezeroes = "00"

print(list(map(lambda x: x.ljust(4, "0"), time_vector)))
```

**Output:**

```
['0600',
 '0700',
 '0800',
 '0900',
 '1000',
 '1100',
 '1200',
 '1300',
 '1400',
 '1500',
 '1600',
 '1700',
 '1800',
 '1900',
 '2000',
 '2100',
 '2200',
 '2300',
 '0000',
 '0100',
 '0200',
 '0300',
 '0400',
 '0500',
 '0600']
```